# How can I run image in the background in Android?

Tags: android, service

In Android Studio, I have image that I need to run in the background as a service. Every 20 seconds I need to show this image and then hide the image. How can I do this?

```
searchMenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.menu);
viewOrder = (Button) findViewById(R.id.order);
popUp = new PopupWindow(this);

// layout = new LinearLayout(this);
layout = new FrameLayout(this);


viewOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (click) {
            popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT,
                    0, 0);
            popUp.update(30, 75, 500, 400);
            click = false;
        } else {
            popUp.dismiss();
            click = true;
        }

    }
});

// popUp.setContentView(layout);

params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.order_back);
// layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
popUp.setContentView(layout);
```

}

}

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images are supposed be in foreground. I am not sure why you want to run in background as a service. To achieve based on image.

1. Two set of Images, One with Eye open and eye close.draw it on top of each other
2. use a handler or timer to hide Eye Open image every 20 secs, which inturn displays the eye closed image creating the effect as shown in the screenshot.
3. you don't need a service for this. Activity can be used to achieve it.